# Stripe Webhook fails to fire, write data to firebase

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a webhook I'm using to write data to firebase when a stripe purchase happens, and I cant get it to work.
I've tried adding try/catch statements around everything, i cant seem to catch the error regardless.

Im using the nextJS backed debugging as found here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging

My question is why? all my api keys are correct.

the error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "http://localhost:3000/api/webhook": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

The Webhook:

```
import { buffer } from "micro";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

//secure a connection to firebase
const serviceAccount = require("../../../permissions.json");

const app = !admin.apps.length
  ? admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    })
  : admin.app();

//connect to stripe

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;

const fullfillOrder = async (session) => {
  try {
    return app
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(session.metadata.email)
      .collection("orders")
      .doc(session.id)
      .set({
        amount: session.amount_total / 100,
        amount_shipping: session.total_details.amount_shipping / 100,
        images: JSON.parse(session.metadata.images),
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`SUCCESS : Order ${session.id} has been added to DB.`);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const requestBuffer = await buffer(req);
    const payload = requestBuffer.toString();
    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    let event;

    //verify that event posted from stripe
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error : ${err.message}`);
    }

    //Handle checkout session completed event
    try {
      if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
        const session = event.data.object;

        return fullfillOrder(session)
          .then(() => res.status(200))
          .catch((err) =>
            res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error :${err.message}`)
          );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(" ~ file: webhook.js ~ line 56 ~ error", error);
    }
  }
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
    externalResolver: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: Those 500s aren't coming from Stripe, but rather from your webserver. It seems that you have a bug somewhere in your webhook processing code which is causing your server to return a 500 response code. I'd add some debugging and perhaps some more try/catch statements to see where the problem lies.

Comment: I don't see any of your existing try-catch responding with 500 error. Can you please try wrapping all the functions in a try-catch and share the error.

Comment: @PaulAsjes I've tried adding a try/catch it doesn't seem to help ,I did manage to get the error changed to 400 unsure what I  did there, I posted the new hook anyway

Comment: You're getting a 404 because you configured the CLI to hit `http://localhost:3000/api/webook`. You probably meant `http://localhost:3000/api/webhook`. You need to debug the original 500 error by adding try/catches and logging the exact error that you're getting.

Comment: I think I added a try catch to anything possible if the code no?

Comment: @PaulAsjes added a screenshot and another try/catch

Comment: Those errors are a red herring. `q.stripe.com` is Stripe's metrics domain, they are being blocked likely because you have an ad blocker installed. You wouldn't find errors relating to webhooks in a web browser, Stripe sends webhooks via an HTTP POST request. You should be looking at your server logs rather than a browser console.

Comment: @PaulAsjes I understand now, facing a new problem however .
I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

> when you found this error on console [ERROR] Failed to POST: Post
> "http://localhost:3000/api/webhook": context deadline exceeded
> (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
>
> so , its clear that strip will send this error when your webhook api
> is not sending 200 status code for previous webhook calls.
>
> make sure inside webhook API you send the response properly with 200
> status code
>
> you can log and you can use try/catch for better handling